# How to test if TreeView Nodes and/or Nodes Children are checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, treeview, nodes

I have a program with a TreeView list containing Nodes, and Nodes with Children. These all have the checkbox property enables. I need to know how to check what Nodes / node children are checked. So far I have been able to successfully test for the parent nodes, but no children using:

```
//this  will turn black any node that is checked, doesn't affect the children though
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = this.treeView1.Nodes;
                foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
                {
                    if (n.Checked)
                    {
                        n.BackColor = Color.Black;   
                    }
                }
```

How do I get it to check the parent nodes, as well as the children? I have searched and not found anything that cleared this up for me.

Comment: TreeNode.BackColor will have no effect unless you are OwnerDrawing the treeview.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but it works fine for me.

Comment: huh.  Coulda sworn TreeNode.backColor didn't do anything.  My mistake.  Thanks for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14531278/922198

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a recursive function that will mark all selected items:

```
private static void MarkSelectedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        if (n.Checked)
            n.BackColor = Color.Black;

        MarkSelectedNodes(n.Nodes);
    }
}
```

and call it like so:

```
MarkSelectedNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
```

Comment: Null check?

if(nodes != null)

Comment: @user959729: nodes will only be null if someone passes null.  If you use `Treview.Nodes` or `TreeNode.Nodes` you will never get a null.

Comment: @user959729 just like Dan-o explained, the `Nodes` collection of a `TreeNode` is not null by default, but an empty `TreeNodeCollection`, so the above code would run fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also "unroll" the recursion to improve performance and avoid stack overflow:

```
private static void MarkSelectedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    Stack<TreeNode> toProcess =
        new Stack<TreeNode>(nodes.OfType<TreeNode>());

    while (toProcess.Count != 0)
    {
        TreeNode node = toProcess.Pop();
        if (node.Checked)
            node.BackColor = Color.Black;

        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            toProcess.Push(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you needed to drop down one more level into the child nodes. Same code, just another loop:

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes = this.treeView1.Nodes;
        foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode c in n.Nodes)
            {
                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                }
            }
            if (n.Checked)
            {
                n.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Recursion is better so that any node depth can be supported.

Comment: Was more of a "why its not working" rather than a usable example. Not sure of the down vote because it is an answer none the less.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode>
                           GetAllCheckedChildNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tmpNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            if (tmpNode.Checked)
            {
                yield return tmpNode;
            }

            foreach (var x in GetAllCheckedChildNodes(tmpNode))
            {
                yield return x;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkedNodes = GetAllheckedChildNodes(MyRootNode);
        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
        {
            checkedNode.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will do the job i guess!